# can i zoom winform area around mouse cursor

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, zooming

One of my client's sight is very week he wants a tool in his winform application where he move the mouse courser and particular area around it gets zoomed in 
or any similar control i've searched on google but can't find any third party or builten tool. can you suggest me something ?

Answer (score 1):

You could show your client a Windows Magnifier. It works exactly as you described

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier

Answer (score 1):

you dont need a custom control: your client can use the [Windows magnifier](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/11542/windows-use-magnifier).

It is includend in every windows version starting from windows 7. .

If it is used in "[lens view](https://youtu.be/DiQLHunSjNc?t=100)" it behaves like your client wants.